# Сущность нестатических внутренних классов

Tags: java

Допустим у меня есть класс `А` и внутренний класс `А.В`, и я создаю объект класса `А.В` в методе другого класса (не `А`).

```
A obj1 = new A();
A.B obj2 = obj1.new B();
```

Что есть объект `obj2`? Он является частью `obj1` или самостоятельным независимым обьектом?

Я имею ввиду, что сущность единичного обьекта заключается в чем-то единичном, к примеру, экземпляр `Apple`, который содержит данные-член `сорт` и функцию-член `упастьСВетки()`. В чем смысл внутреннего класса в этом же ключе? Можно ли привести подобный пример для внутренних классов?

Comment: Что именно вас интересует? `obj2` - это отдельный объект в памяти, но имеющий доступ к полям и методам внешнего класса.

Comment: и хранящий внутри себя указатель на внешний класс, поэтому без создания внешнего класс, создать внутренний нельзя. Поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос, скорее часть obj1 чем самостоятельный объект.

Comment: Я имею в виду, для какой цели вы бы использовали внутренний класс?

Comment: используют, если это относиться к одному объекту и нигде почти не используется. 
у Яблоко есть сорт. сорты моогут быть объявлены внутри класса.
Вес может быть отдельно, так ка ВЕС можно применить и  к Грушам

Comment: Я использую для целей удобства. Если класс должен видеть поля внешнего класса и он короткий, то удобно поместить исходный код прямо во внешний класс. И так файлов .java до хрена и больше получается.

Comment: Нужны внутренние классы для реализаций всяческих слушателей событий, особенно при разработке UI. Еще асинхронные задачи делают через них.

Answer (score 2):

Они нужны для того, чтобы иметь ссылку на внешний класс, в который они были вложены. Иногда объекты каких то классов сами по себе имеют мало ценности без привязки его к какому то элементу.

Приведу банальный пример, будьте осторожны, он несколько натянут. У нас есть родитель у него есть дети. Для получения полного имени потомка, нужно иметь ссылку на родитель. И тут есть несколько вариантов: использовать явно поле с ссылкой на родителя или же воспользоваться функциями языка (inner class).

```
class Parent {
    private String name;

    public Child createChild(String name) {
        return new Child(name);
    }

    public class Child {
        private String name;

        private Child(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getFullName() {
            return name + " " + Parent.this.name;
        }
    }
}
```